# How to select a default item (itemTag) when initializing the page and when singleItem = true in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, tags

I want to select an item by default, I use ItemTags with `singleItem: true` for all and `active:true` just for one item. But it doesn't select item. Maybe because singleItem is true??! I tried with `singleItem: false` it worked, but for my project I need SINGLE SELECTION, how to do that?
Thank you.

My ItemTags is like...

```
 ItemTags(
     key: GlobalKey(debugLabel: index.toString()),
     index: index, // required
     title: TranslationDictionary.instance[item.name],
     customData: item,
     singleItem: true,
     active: _active, // even it's true, it doesn't select item (because singleItem is true?? but why??)
     elevation: 0,
     borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),            
     onPressed: (item) {
       setState(() {
          if (item.active) {
            ...
          } else {
            ...
          });
      },
 );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried myself and it definitely works with this:

```
return ItemTags(
        // Each ItemTags must contain a Key. Keys allow Flutter to
        // uniquely identify widgets.
        key: Key(index.toString()),
        index: index, // required
        title: item,
        active: false,
        singleItem: true,
        customData: index,
        textStyle: TextStyle(
          fontSize: _fontSize,
        ),
        combine: ItemTagsCombine.withTextBefore,
        icon: ItemTagsIcon(
          icon: Icons.add,
        ), // OR null, // OR null,
      );
```

itemBuilder's Tags attribute is a loop so the active property should set to false,
and singleItem to true to avoid multiple selections.

***EDIT***: It seems that if you set up with singleItem to true, you can't initiate with an item to active, see below in their package.

> active: widget.singleItem ? false : widget.active,

It means that it doesn't care about your active property if you set the singleItem to true. So you can't do this.

For me, there are 2 solutions:

## Solution 1

You modify by yourself the package, see : https://medium.com/flutter-community/how-to-modify-an-existing-pub-package-to-use-in-your-flutter-project-4e909452ee66

## Solution 2

Simulate a tap on the screen to choose the right item which has to be selected

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I don't know how to simulate a tap on the screen for this element. Can you help me please